# How to place MySql DATETIME results into HTML input with type datetime-local

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

[image: that the output of my code]

i stored date using `<input type="datetime-local">` in the database now i want to get back the date in `<input type="datetime-local">` for update purpose.

i am doing

```
$query="select * from exam_schedule where subject_name='$name' AND class_id='$schedule_id' limit 1";
$result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($read_all_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 

echo "date comming from datebase::".$date=$read_all_data['date_and_time']."<br>";
echo "duration comming from datebase::".$duration=$read_all_data['duration'];

$duration=$read_all_data['duration'];
echo "<form method='post' action='edit_schedule.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>";
echo  "<tr><th><input type='datetime-local' name='date' value='$date'> </th>";
echo  "<th><input type='datetime-local' name='duration' value='$duration'> </th>";
echo <input type='submit' name='update' value='update'> </form></th></tr>";
}
```

when i echo the $date and $duration it shows me values but when i put value="$date" it doesnot show me date from database.

Comment: provide the structure of your SQL table.

Comment: what do you see when you `echo $date` ?

Comment: what's "updation" supposed to represent? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68169/is-updation-a-correct-word

Comment: id     type =INT
date_and_time    type=DATETIME
duration               type =DATETIME

Comment: it shows me correct values of date coming from database. but i want values in  "datetime" field.

Comment: you have a syntax error here `echo  "<th><input type='datetime-local' name='duration' value='$duration'> </th>";
<input type='submit' name='update' value='update'> </form></th></tr>";` and error reporting would've told you that. Missing an `echo "`.

Comment: did you forget the last echo?

Comment: I think the value is actually there, but your browser is not displaying it. Have you checked it using your browser's web inspector?

Comment: somebody's bound to bite/chew/gnaw on my comment about the syntax error.

Comment: codegodie sorry i accidentally erase the echo while pasting code on stackoverflow. but i have "echo" in my code.

Comment: you should edit your question and fix it.

Comment: lol good thing I made that as a comment. Some vamp would've been caught with their pants down.

Comment: lol @Fred-ii- you never fail to pull a finger..

Comment: @CodeGodie Pull my finger.... *grin* hahaha! (joke). ;-)

Comment: http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Pull_43cfea_602437.jpg

Comment: i have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: @CodeGodie [*You crack me up*](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3073/2918986212_93ae26cb95.jpg?v=0)

Comment: as per your edit, you're trying to echo mm-dd-YY when MySQL stores DATETIME as YYYY-mm-dd.

Comment: but it stored date using the same input field

Comment: Did you check your browser's web inspector to see if the value is actually there? You can also try your source code.

Comment: *I'm out of this loop*.

Comment: i think Fred-ii- is right . mysql stores data and time in yyyy-mm-dd and input filed "datetime " shows in mm-dd-yyyy. thats why its not showing me values. 
p.s i have checked browser's web inspector there are no values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `datetime-local` input type expects the date to be in this format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm` but you are supplying it the default `DATETIME` format created by the database which is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1o57574h/)

In order to change it, you need to change your SQL query to this:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_and_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') AS custom_date 
FROM exam_schedule 
WHERE subject_name='$name' 
AND class_id='$schedule_id' 
LMIT 1
```

so now in your results, you can then use the `custom_date` to prefill your input.

```
<input type='datetime-local' name='date' value='<?php echo $row['custom_date'] ?>' >
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to convert the time in PHP instead of MySQL:

1. Convert the MySQL datetime string into a PHP timestamp
2. Apply a PHP date format mask to the PHP timestamp, where the format matches the HTML5 datetime-local format

PHP code sample:

```
const HTML_DATETIME_LOCAL = 'Y-m-d\TH:i'; //escape the literal T so it is not expanded to a timezone code
$php_timestamp = strtotime($mysql_date_string);
$html_datetime_string = date(HTML_DATETIME_LOCAL, $php_timestamp);
echo "<input type='datetime-local' name='date' value='{$html_datetime_string}'>";
```

Comment: This is not working for me: it is not showing in the input.

Comment: Updated. Thanks. Fixed $ for variable in string.

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
 <?php  echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($exampledate));?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this one:

```
date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: where can he use this code, why would they use this code, and how will it solve the problem?

Comment: it will format the date as **2013-03-15 00:00:00**.
Wherever you want date format like this, you can use.